# Elements of type 'Module' are not supported at the 'Farm' scope. This feature could not be installed

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am packaging my Project into .wsp using the WSPBuilder Extension ->Build WSP. Once I run the `stsadm -o addsoltion -filename myWsp.wsp and go to deploy the soltion I get this:

**Elements of type 'Module' are not supported at the 'Farm' scope.  This feature could not be installed.**

Now I have a whole bunch of features that I have inhereted from previos developers and those features somehow had been deployed but I don't know how. 
Can someone help me to actually fix the error and deploy what I need?

Some of them look like this (the manifest.xml):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400BE0CE07B5D2F45ef8EF5235741C789B9" Name="Test Portal Web Part Page"
             Description="Web Part Page for Test Portal."
             Version="1"
             Group="MyCompany Test Portal">
</ContentType>

<!-- Master Page Catalogs -->
<Module Name="PageLayoutsModule" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" RootWebOnly="True" Path="pagelayouts">
    <File Url="main.master" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
    <File Url="BeaconLayout.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Test Portal Web Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400BE0CE07B5D2F45ef8EF5235741C789B9;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="BeaconLayout2.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Test Portal Web Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400BE0CE07B5D2F45ef8EF5235741C789B9;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="OneColumnLayout.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Test Portal Web Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400BE0CE07B5D2F45ef8EF5235741C789B9;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="TwoColumnLayout.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Test Portal Web Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400BE0CE07B5D2F45ef8EF5235741C789B9;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="ThreeColumnLayout.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Test Portal Web Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400BE0CE07B5D2F45ef8EF5235741C789B9;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="PrintLayout.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Test Portal Web Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400BE0CE07B5D2F45ef8EF5235741C789B9;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="MyCompanyArticleLinks.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="MyCompanyArticle.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="MyCompanyArticleRightImage.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="MyCompanyWelcomePage.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="MyCompanyWelcomePage2.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"></Property>
    </File>
    <File Url="MyCompanyArticleRightWebParts.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLinks.png"></Property>
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                  Value=";#Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"></Property>
    </File>
</Module>
<!-- Site Pages -->
<Module Name="PagesModule" Url="Pages" RootWebOnly="True" Path="Pages">
    <File Url="ResetForgottenPassword.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Header" WebPartOrder="0">
            <![CDATA[
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                    <webParts>
                        <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                            <metaData>
                                <type name="MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss.WebParts.ResetDomainPasswordWebPart, MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4e32e6f1096bb318"/>
                                <importErrorMessage>Cannot import the Forgotten Password Reset Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                            </metaData>
                            <data>
                                <properties>
                                    <property name="Title" type="string">MyCompany Test Portal Forgotten Password Reset Web Part</property>
                                    <property name="Description" type="string">MyCompany Test Portal Forgotten Password Reset Web Part</property>
                                    <property name="Group" type="string">MyCompany</property>
                                </properties>
                            </data>
                        </webPart>
                    </webParts>
            ]]>
        </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
    <File Url="SecretQAManage.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Header" WebPartOrder="0">
            <![CDATA[
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                <webParts>
                    <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                        <metaData>
                            <type name="MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss.WebParts.SecretQAManageWebPart, MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4e32e6f1096bb318" />
                            <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                        </metaData>
                        <data>
                            <properties>
                                <property name="Title" type="string">MyCompany Test Portal Secret Questions &amp; Answers Management Web Part</property>
                                <property name="Description" type="string">MyCompany Test Portal Secret Questions &amp; Answers Management Web Part</property>
                                <property name="Group" type="string">MyCompany</property>
                            </properties>
                        </data>
                    </webPart>
                </webParts>
            ]]>
        </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
    <File Url="UserManagement.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="MainWebPartZone" WebPartOrder="0">
            <![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <webParts>
                <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                    <metaData>
                        <type name="MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss.WebParts.SsoUserCredentialsWebPart, MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4e32e6f1096bb318" />
                        <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                    </metaData>
                    <data>
                        <properties>
                            <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
                            <property name="Title" type="string"> SSO User Credentials Web Part</property>
                            <property name="Description" type="string">MyCompany Test Portal SSO User Credentials Web Part</property>
                            <property name="Group" type="string">MyCompany</property>
                        </properties>
                    </data>
                </webPart>
            </webParts>
            ]]>
        </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
    <File Url="ChangePassword.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="MainWebPartZone" WebPartOrder="0">
            <![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <webParts>
                <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                    <metaData>
                        <type name="MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss.WebParts.ChangePasswordWebPart, MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4e32e6f1096bb318" />
                        <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                    </metaData>
                    <data>
                        <properties>
                            <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
                            <property name="Title" type="string"> Change  Password Web Part</property>
                            <property name="Description" type="string">MyCompany Test Portal Change  Password Web Part</property>
                            <property name="Group" type="string">MyCompany</property>
                        </properties>
                    </data>
                </webPart>
                </webParts>
            ]]>
        </AllUsersWebPart>
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="MainWebPartZone" WebPartOrder="0">
            <![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <webParts>
                <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                    <metaData>
                        <type name="MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss.WebParts.ChangeNetworkPasswordWebPart, MyCompany.TestPortal.Moss, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4e32e6f1096bb318" />
                        <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                    </metaData>
                    <data>
                        <properties>
                            <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
                            <property name="Title" type="string"> Change Network Password Web Part</property>
                            <property name="Description" type="string">MyCompany Test Portal Change Network Password Web Part</property>
                            <property name="Group" type="string">MyCompany</property>
                        </properties>
                    </data>
                </webPart>
                </webParts>
            ]]>
        </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
</Module>
```

-->

Answer (score 1):

You have probably already sorted this problem out.

If not, the problem seems to be with your scope, which is defined in the *Feature.xml* file (not Elements.xml). I.e. change it from `Farm` to `Site`:

`<Feature ... Scope="Site" ...>`